# How to Pass a value from One User Control to another in WPF.

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, window

I am developing the GUI of my Project as a UserControl in WPF. And I'm trying to use it in another WPF Window. It works fine but the real problem is passing a particular value from one user control to another.

```
eg: 
UserControl1 is displayed within WPFWindow1 
UserControl2 is displayed within WPFWindow2 

MainWindow opens Window1 , Window1 opens Window 2 .
```

So the requirement is that in Window2 , when the User clicked the button it should pass a value to Window1 .

Here is a sample Project I did to make it understand better (Just in Case) :http://goo.gl/h0zpL7

Comment: The proper way to do this is with databinding to a 'Model' class. UserControls should not know or require each other. Your goal should probably be to learn MVVM but you can solve your curent problem with only the basic elements of databinding.

Comment: "when the User clicked the button it should pass a value to Window1" which means you should show the Window1 again with the Passed value

Comment: Yeah. It should be displayed in a TextBox or Label (in any control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `Delegates` and `Events` are the best practice I can suggest. Create a `Delegate` and `Event` in Window2 like below

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate(object value);
    public event MyDelegate MyCustomEvent;

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCustomEvent(100);
    }
}
```

Subscribe the `MyCustomEvent` in Window1 like below

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 wnd = new Window2();
        wnd.MyCustomEvent += wnd_MyCustomEvent;
        wnd.Show();
    }

    void wnd_MyCustomEvent(object value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: But I dont use any buttons within the Windows. All the implementation is done in the user control and it's dragged and dropped within the window. (Correct me If i'm wrong) Did u check the SAMPLE file ?

Comment: Instead of window you can do the same in UserControl also. Delegate will work as the same. Here all you have to do is implement the delegate inside the User control button